# How to display Back-end response in Sweetalart2

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert2

I am trying to display back-end error responses in Sweetalert2 message.
I was able to display Error text but I couldn't display specific error response messages I am getting from the back-end.

For Example, if I type wrong username, I get the API response "{"message":"User Not Found"}"

If I type wrong password, I get the API response "{"message":"Authentication Failed"}"

In the following code I changed the SweetAlert title to 'title: error.statusText' and it only display 'Bad request'

How can I display specific error messages I am getting from backend, instead of error status text?

Also, I don't know why my console.log(error) not working in the following code block.

```
signIn() {
this.authService.login(this.Username, this.Password).subscribe(
  (data) => localStorage.setItem('Token', data),
  (error) => Swal({
    title: error.statusText,
    type: 'warning',
    confirmButtonText: 'Try Again'
  }),
//console.log(error)
  function (complete) {
    Swal({
      toast: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Login Successful!',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 3200
    })
    this.router.navigate(['/userDashboard']);
    this.authService.setLoggedIn(true)
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the title to error.message

```
(error) => Swal({
    title: error.message,
    type: 'warning',
    confirmButtonText: 'Try Again'
}),
```

Comment: error.message returns:  Http failure response for http://dev.site/api/user/authenticate: 400 Bad Request